Sump pump not turning on
I had installed a new sump pump in my basement and since then the sump pump has not turned on. The person who installed it states that when the water level is too high then only it will turn on but if there are drops of water coming it will flow through downward without turning on the sump pump. They intentionally created a hole where the water just flows instead of the level of water going higher. Can anyone please explain if this is right?

Sump. We might need a photo here. This "hole" is a bit confusing. Please use the editor to upload a clear photo.

There are stones on top of hole so it's not visible. But the guy said it just goes very down to the house if its drops of water.

I'm having trouble with your English. Can you get some help with that? We need to understand the problem before we can provide answers.

Sump pump is installed. Its not getting turned on if there are drops of water. The guys who installed said if there are drops of water it will flow through a small hole which goes down. Sump pump does not fill water if it is drops of water but if there is a lot of water, it turns on. Is this normal?

Yes, sump pumps are for removing large amounts of water. They don't do anything if you just have a little bit that soaks into the ground. I guess I was confused because I wouldn't expect a pump to handle drops.

use a garden hose and fill up the pit till the pump starts

Sump pumps have an adjustable switch, usually a float, that water will raise up to turn on the pump.  You usually want the water at least half way up the pit before the pump turns on.

Yes, that's a very normal situation with a sump.
To check that it comes on as it should, rapidly add water to the sump (faster than it flows out) to cause the pump to activate. This might be possible with a hose or you may need a bucket, or even several full buckets dumped rapidly, depending on the normal outflow rate.
